# Airflow: how to achieve to get the from a windows server to linux

Tags: windows, ssh, airflow, winrm

We are trying to connect to windows server from Airflow to pick some text files and keep it into Linux.

We tried installing SSH setup in windows and connection is getting established but as in linux we have directory structure in different way when we compare with windows

```
linux: /home/aarya/
windows: \home\  or c:\
```

we tried scp or sftp but none of them are working.

is there a way we can achieve to connect to windows and copy the file to linux

any sample dag reference
(we tried Airflow provider Winrm as well but it says an

```
error : the specified credentials were rejected by the server

        from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import yaml,os,pendulum
    from airflow import DAG

    from airflow.providers.microsoft.winrm.hooks.winrm import WinRMHook
    from airflow.providers.microsoft.winrm.operators.winrm import WinRMOperator

    try:
        from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator as EmptyOperator  # type: ignore


    with DAG(
        dag_id=os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".py",""),
        schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 2),
        tags=['example'],
        catchup=False,
    ) as dag:

        run_this_last = EmptyOperator(task_id='run_this_last')

        # [START create_hook]
        winRMHook = WinRMHook(ssh_conn_id='windows_ssh_connectionparam')
        # [END create_hook]

        # [START run_operator]
        t1 = WinRMOperator(task_id="wintask1", command='ls -altr', winrm_hook=winRMHook)

        t2 = WinRMOperator(task_id="wintask2", command='sleep 60', winrm_hook=winRMHook)

        t3 = WinRMOperator(task_id="wintask3", command='echo \'luke test\' ', winrm_hook=winRMHook)
        # [END run_operator]

        [t1, t2, t3] >> run_this_last
```

Is there any other way other than WINRM pls or any reference dag

Comment: What did you end up doing?